# Why do expression need to be in parentheses for an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

In creating the second array in the files1 array, the mathematical expressions must be placed in parentheses. Does the hierarchy of operators not apply here?

```
PS C:\src\powershell> Get-Content .\fr-btest2.ps1
$files1 = @(
, @(4, 1024)
, @(2*3, 4*5)
)

$files1
$files1.GetType()
$files1.Length
$files1.Count

'============'

$files2 = @(
, @(4, 1024)
, @((2*3), (4*5))
)

$files2
$files2.GetType()
$files2.Length
$files2.Count
PS C:\src\powershell> .\fr-btest2.ps1
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Multiply'.
At C:\src\powershell\fr-btest2.ps1:3 char:5
+ , @(2*3, 4*5)
+     ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Multiply:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

4
1024

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
2
2
============
4
1024
6
20
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
2
2
```

Comment: It's a good question, but I suggest you reduce it to an MCVE: `@(2*3, 4*5)` or even `2*3, 4*5` is sufficient to produce the symptom, and `(2*3), (4*5)` is sufficient to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`,` (the array-construction operator) has higher precedence than `*`** - see [`Get-Help about_Operator_Precedence`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847842.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

<sup>Note: The following snippets do *not* use array subexpression operator `@(...)`, because it is not necessary to specify array literals - array-construction operator `,` is sufficient.</sup>

Therefore,

```
2*3, 4*5
```

is parsed as:

```
2 * (3, 4) * 5
```

and PowerShell doesn't know how to use an array on the RHS of `*`.

Using parentheses for explicit precedence is required:
`(2*3), (4*5)` yields the desired array, `6, 20`.

---

*As an aside*: PowerShell supports arrays on the *LHS* of `*`, albeit not in a numeric sense: Using an array as the LHS (flatly) *replicates* that array as often as specified on the (scalar, numeric) RHS - analogous to how *strings* on the LHS can be replicated with `*`:

```
> (2,3) * 2  # equivalent of: 2, 3, 2, 3
2
3
2
3
```

---

#### Possible motivation for the precedence rule

While I do not really know the design rationale for giving `,` higher precedence than operators such as `*`, one possible reason comes to mind:

Some PowerShell operators - notably `-replace` and `-split` - take an *array* as their RHS.

With `,` having higher precedence, expressions such as the following are possible, without needing to use parentheses around the elements of the RHS:

```
> 'A barl and his money are soon parted.' -replace 'bar', 'foo'
A fool and his money are soon parted.
```

If my own real-world experience is anything to go by, running into this precedence issue it unexpected ways such as in this question is *rare*.

Comment: I will select this as the correct answer because it is. It is not because I think this language syntax is a good. idea at this point in time. Surely, there is something more that I don't understand yet to make this a good idea.